# what does「デカいヤマをあてること」mean?

Tags: grammar

As someone with little to no knowledge on japanese, I've cracked my brain as to unfurl this passage's meaning.

Here's the full sentence:

> 夢は「デカいヤマをあてること」

夢は roughly being "What's your dream?" or something along the lines of "Your dream:".

I come to realize that こと usually eliminates ambiguity, but that's as far as my knowledge reaches.

Comment: http://www.waeijisho.net/word.html?id=70787

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the breakdown:

- **夢**: "dream"
- **は**: topic marker
- **「**: Japanese opening quotation mark
- **デカい**: "big", "huge"
- **ヤマをあてる**: set phrase meaning "to make a killing", "to grab a chance", etc
- **こと**: "-ing", nominalizer (turns a verb into a noun)
- **」**: Japanese closing quotation mark

So the sentence means "My/His/Her dream is grabbing a big chance (and become rich)." Since the sentence lacks a personal pronoun that corresponds to *my/your/etc*, you have to determine whose dream the sentence is talking about from the context. If there is no further context at all (e.g., it's printed on a T-shirt), it should mean "*My* dream is..."

Comment: The breakdown helped me get a better grasp at the sentence. Also big thanks on clarifying the こと meaning, its usage escaped my mind for the longest time. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score -1):

I wished to help -- since I had a similar question a month ago -- but my Japanese is rusty.

This is a rough translation: *A dream: "To move mountains."* possibly in a sense of "accomplishing big feats".

ヤマ is katakana of 山 which means *mountain*. I don't usually see 山 in its katakana form, oddly enough.

Comment: あてる is not "move" but would rather be like "touch, aim for"

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I guess I was jumping to a more literal translation in order to make sense. Could "Reach for" be a loose suggestion to this as well?